# Problems installing Desktop

Tags: installation

I try to boot from cd. Get the menu, tell it to either install or run from CD and i just get a lot of hex binary items and it will not install. System Asus A7S333 1250mb ram

Comment: My first guess is a corrupt CD or a corrupt download used to burn the CD. Just out of curiosity, what are you installing? Cuz Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 are both to large to fit on a CD, and require a DVD or a USB drive to install from.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Post 12.04 versions are difficult to install via CD given the hardware limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop for several times and I never encountered such problem. Looks like your guessing is right. Either your CD or your downloaded copy of Ubuntu has corrupted.

Generally a CD have around 700MB storage. But size of Ubuntu is a little bit larger than that. So, you need a DVD.(Some CD may have the required amount of storage. But it's not common.)